# QuillJS issue when adding name="body"

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, quill

i have QuillJS issue when adding name="body"

```
<div id="editor">
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Some initial <strong>bold</strong> text</p>
  <p><br></p>
</div>
```

when using this i cannot add name="body" to it as it errors out on submit :/ any ideas how i can use this to post content

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: ```QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: blogs.body (SQL: insert into "blogs" ("user_id", "name", "slug", "label", "twitter", "website", "body", "updated_at", "created_at") values (2, hello, hello, Web, hello, https://google.com, , 2017-08-09 14:39:22, 2017-08-09 14:39:22))```

Comment: i need to use name="body" to collect the contents of form and display it however if i use it using textarea it works but then doesnt allow for toolbar to work using the method shown above lets toolbar work but then breaks on submit